# What is a user friendly ebook converter for pc to Nook HD+?

Tags: ebook

I've tried using calibre, but it cuts out or messes with the original text from the pdf. I don't want to just give up and read from my computer, so any ideas? (please posts links if any.)

Comment: Why do you need to convert from pdf?  I think there are apps like ezpdf to read them on the nook.

Comment: Are you looking for an OSX or a Windows solution?

Comment: The issue is that pdf is designed for the page size the author wants and there is not enough information in the pdf to convert it automatically into a flowing format like epub sothere is probably nothing that much better than calibre unless you program for each pdf

Answer (score 3):

[Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) is without a doubt the best ebook library converter/manager I've ever used.  Free and crossplatform for Mac, Linux, and Windows.